# disable ime mode in google chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, ime

How to disable IME using css or anyother method ?My problem is that,When change language to japanese,Double byte numbers are entered in text box,I need to prevent this

I use

```
     style="ime-mode:disabled"
```

It works all other browsers except google chrome.

Comment: For reference this will *only* work in Firefox and IE. Chrome isn't the only browser this won't work in.

Comment: can you suggest a solution?

Comment: I can't I'm afraid. I did a bit of searching and it seems the general consensus is that `ime-mode` 1. could do more harm than good, and 2. shouldn't have been added as a style in the first place - you can thank Microsoft for that one. I haven't worked with languages other than English before so I'm unable to give any recommendations.

Answer (score 9):

change the attribute type to tel. It works just like ime-mode is inactive in chrome and other browsers supports html5.

```
element.setAttribute('type', 'tel');
```

I recommend you to use both **ime-mode** and **type="tel"**

**style: ime-mode**

```
Chrome          Firefox (Gecko)     IE        Opera             Safari (WebKit)
Not supported   3.0 (1.9)           5.0       Not supported     Not supported
```

**input type="tel"**

```
Chrome      Firefox         IE      Opera           Safari      Safari Mobile
6+          4+              10+     10.6+           5.1+        iOS 3.1+
```

**Using Both**

```
Chrome      Firefox         IE      Opera           Safari      Safari Mobile
6+          3.0 (1.9)       5.0     10.6+           5.1+        iOS 3.1+
```

Comment: I now use Chrome 68 but this attribute setting is not do as I want it to be.
It still be able to enter double byte number when change keyboard into Japanese and change IME to Japanese Kana keyboard layout.